# Insert solve in VBA function causing #value err

Tags: excel, solver, vba

I would like to put solver into a function like this

Function calIRR() As Variant

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$E$47", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$D$48", Engine _
    :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
 SolverSolve
  SendKeys "~"
```

calIRR = Range("$D$48").value

End Function

but it keeps causing #VALUE error. Everything works correctly when I change to procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the workbook and sorksheet to whom the range belongs to. Try out the below code:

callRR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D48").Value

Where Sheet1 is your sheetName

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but it still doesn't work, When I debug, After the cursor moves to second line (SolverOk....), it just steps out and gives no results. If I keep press F8 for few more rounds, now it begins to move to next line. So weird!